# Compute Expectation of Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory

I need to solve this task  and find

$\mathbb{E}^*(Y)$

Under following conditions
The measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and the random variables X and Y by $X(\omega)=|\omega|$ and $Y(\omega)=\omega^2$. Define the measures $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}$* as

$\mathbb{P}:=0.3\delta_0+0.4\delta_1+0.3\delta_2,\quad \frac{d\mathbb{P}^*}{d\mathbb{P}}=X.$

My solution

${\mathbb{P}^*}={\mathbb{P}}*X=0.3*|0|*\delta_0+0.4*|1|*\delta_1+0.3*|2|*\delta_2
=0.4\delta_1+0.6\delta_2
$

$ \mathbb{E}^*(Y)=\sum\limits_{\omega}Y(\omega)*\mathbb{P}^*=
Y(1)*0.4+Y(2)*0.6=0.4+4*0.6=2.8
$

Do you think this is correct answer.